# Need to print all the missing value column names in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008-r2

I need all the column names missing mandatory values in a single string, in a select statement shown below.

I have tried using CASE statement but it was not working since it will omit the second condition if first one matches.

```
SELECT
    stg2.StageID
    ,[CSP]
    ,[CSPRegionID]
    ,[SoldToCompanyID]
    ,[EndUserCompanyID]
    ,[SupportOptionID]
    ,'One/More Mandatory value/s is/are missing' FailureReason
    ,CASE   WHEN stg2.CSP IS NULL THEN @FailureDetails + 'CSP' 
            WHEN stg2.CSPRegionID IS NULL THEN @FailureDetails + 'CSP Region' 
            WHEN stg2.SoldToCompanyID IS NULL THEN @FailureDetails + 'SoldToCompany' 
            WHEN stg2.EndUserCompanyID IS NULL THEN @FailureDetails + 'EndUserCompany' 
            WHEN stg2.SupportOptionID IS NULL THEN @FailureDetails + 'SupportOption' 
    END FailureDetails
FROM [EntitlementTracker_SRV4Stage].[dbo].[srv4_ClassicLoad_Stage2] stg2
WHERE stg2.CSP IS NULL
OR stg2.CSPRegionID IS NULL
OR stg2.SoldToCompanyID IS NULL
OR stg2.EndUserCompanyID IS NULL 
OR stg2.SupportOptionID IS NULL
```

Anybody please help out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, `CASE` will only evaluate the first case that matches.  I'd suggest something like:

```
,  CASE WHEN stg2.CSP              IS NULL THEN 'CSP, '            ELSE '' END
 + CASE WHEN stg2.CSPRegionID      IS NULL THEN 'CSP Region, '     ELSE '' END
 + CASE WHEN stg2.SoldToCompanyID  IS NULL THEN 'SoldToCompany, '  ELSE '' END
 + CASE WHEN stg2.EndUserCompanyID IS NULL THEN 'EndUserCompany, ' ELSE '' END
 + CASE WHEN stg2.SupportOptionID  IS NULL THEN 'SupportOption, '  ELSE '' END
 FailureDetails
```

Comment: Thanks Stanley.. Suppose if I need to append a string as 'Missing below mandatory values: ' before printing the column names, can you help me how to print it out?

Comment: @prabuR Just add it to the front of the first `CASE` statement:

Comment: @AntonyGibbs `||` operator is not supported in `SQL SERVER`